# Create ssh key for hudson user in openSuse

Tags: ssh, hudson, ssh-keys, opensuse

I have installed hudson in Opensuse machine using following commands.

1. sudo wget -O /etc/zypp/repos.d/hudson.repo http://hudson-ci.org/opensuse/hudson.repo
2. sudo zypper refresh
3. sudo zypper install hudson #(hudson user is created in my machine with hudson home in /var/lib/hudson)
4. cd /etc/init.d
5. passwd hudson #created passowd for hudson user
6. ./hudson start

I **can't able to create ssh key** for the hudson user. Moreover I **cannot able to login as a hudson user**. If I can login as hudson user then I can able to create ssh key. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

OpenSuse (like many systems, btw) prevents login for utility user accounts. This includes hudson, but also apache, rsync or saned, mdm, etc. This is quite fortunate, because if your box is on the www you will soon see in the log brute-force ssh connection attemps on such accounts.

So the solution for you is to generate the ssh key from another non-privileged user and copy the ssh key to the hudson home (/var/lib/hudson/.ssh in your case). As pointed out in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/323958/how-do-you-create-an-ssh-key-for-another-user), ssh keys have no user information so it should work, although you have to be careful with your user identities (e.g. use this key for hudson only, not for the borrowed user account).